# Laravel Uploading online Error index.php require once

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i am beginner laravel programmer , I created a website its working perfectly on local host , i change server.php to index.php for using root directory

but when i upload it on live it gives me error which is

Warning: require_once(/srv/disk11/2451785/www/hiveminds.dx.am/public/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk11/2451785/www/hiveminds.dx.am/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/srv/disk11/2451785/www/hiveminds.dx.am/public/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.6.31/share/pear') in /srv/disk11/2451785/www/hiveminds.dx.am/index.php on line 22

my local url address is

http://localhost/dataform/

my index.php file is

```
    <?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: it's your server.php file man. rename it to server.php your index.php file is in public directory.

Comment: You do not have to change the directory. It is perfectly ready to develop out of the box.

Comment: @Jonjie i tried both ways from public and from moving public files to main root and its not working still stick its my 1st time actually and i cant find solution tried many .

Comment: Is your setup or files/folder directory works on `localhost`?

Comment: yes its working on local host , either i use public folder url or copy paste everything out of public folder to main root both are working locally

Answer (score 1):

if you want your `index.php` file on the root directory, then follow these steps.

**1**. cut your `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from `public/` directory and paste it into your root directory.

**2**. make some changes in index.php to give a path to bootstrap files like this.

Autoload file before change,

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

after making change.

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

bootstrapp app file before change,

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

after changes.

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

now run your app from `http://localhost/dataform/`